# Check if height is lower than parent for each element

Tags: jquery

How can I check for a `div` if it's height is lower than it's parent?

Let's say I have multiple divs with multiple parents with different height on each of them.

Comment: "with multiple parents" ? so have to check the height of the div with multiple parents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `.height()` method.

```
$('div').each(function(){
    if ($(this).height() < $(this).parent().height()) {
      // do something
    }
});
```

To set the height of each child `div` to its parent's, you can put this inside the function:

```
$(this).height($(this).parent().height());
```

Comment: Cool, and how can I apply the resulting height to that `div`? I mean, the height of the parent in that case.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of jQuery **filter()** method you can check all the div elements whose height is less compared to its parent element.

In the below example we are applying the background color to the child elements whose height is less than its parent.

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="par1" class="parentcls" style="height: 10px;">
    <div id="child1" class="childtcls" style="height: 50px;"></div>
</div>
<div id="par2" class="parentcls" style="height: 50px;">
    <div id="child2" class="childtcls" style="height: 70px;"></div>
</div>
<div id="par3" class="parentcls" style="height: 20px;">
    <div id="child3" class="childtcls" style="height: 10px;"></div>
</div>
<div id="par4"  class="parentcls" style="height: 40px;">
    <div id="child4" class="childtcls" style="height: 30px;"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
div {
    width: 100px; 
    border: 1px solid #ff0000; 
    float: left;
}

div.childtcls {
    border: 1px solid #0000ff;
}

div.parentcls {  margin: 10px;}
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$("div").filter(function(index){
    return $( this).height() < $( this ).parent().height();
}).css('background-color', '#00ff00');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o0w27jfs/1/